# How close is JQuery's CDN to my location?

Tags: caching, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy, cdn

Rather than just read theory, I decided to test how JQuery's CDN reduces website latency. My method is pretty basic.

Assuming a web developer places the following JQuery (CDN) tag on a web page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

The DNS lookup for `code.jquery.com` should return the IP of the closest (proxy / caching / CDN) server depending on where I'm located in the World.

I have two IP addresses.

At **work** I go through a proxy, my IP maps to the **United States**. Using my phone's **cellular connection**, my IP address maps to the **United Kingdom** (I am located in the UK). I tested this multiple times.

Using both connections, I performed a DNS lookup on `code.jquery.com`. On both occasions, the IP of a server in United States was returned:

```
code.jquery.com is an alias for code.jquery.netdna-cdn.com.
code.jquery.netdna-cdn.com has address 94.46.159.11
```

I *assumed* a DNS lookup would return a proxy server in Europe (when my IP maps to the United Kingdom) and `jquery-1.12.0.min.js` is served from the closes edge server.

**Update**

I found the article, [Different CDN technologies: DNS Vs Anycast Routing](https://anuragbhatia.com/networking/different-cdn-technologies-dns-vs-anycast-routing/), incredibly useful and I wanted to include it here for others. It covers to two methods for ensuring a user hits an edge caching server that's geographically nearby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same IP from my location (Latvia). But I asked guys from jquery cdn provider (which is maxcdn.com). An they told me this:

> Though the IP itself is registered in US, it's not a standard unicast IP. 
>   This one uses the anycast system, which means it resolves to multiple locations at the same time. 
>   The easiest way you can check that is to do a tracroute to 94.46.159.11 
>   the traceroute will end up in Europe on one of our EU servers.

I've traced the request, and ended up in Frankfurt.

Comment: I tried the same and traceroute on 94.46.159.11 terminated in the US when connecting through a US proxy, and terminated in the UK when connected to via a UK cellular network provider.